# How to uncompress file

Tags: linux, compression

I am trying to uncompress a unknown file type. I used file command

```
file sample.file 
sample.file: gzip compressed data, was "/groupts/7bi/e7/ciuyuyout/Dump/SplitFastq/327264/ou", last modified: Wed May  1 14:27:46 2013, max compression
```

then i used gunzip sample.file

```
gzip: sample.file: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

May i know how can unzip and see its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the file to `sample.file.gz` and rerun `gunzip` on the new file.

```
unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Is telling you that it does not understand the `.file` suffix so it is ignoring the file.